# MySQL: Facing issue in Where clause with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question, so based on my research of MySql JOINS I understand that this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Rule
INNER JOIN RuleList
ON Rule.ruleID = RuleList.ruleID
WHERE Rule.accountID = 'geoskygps@gmail.com'
```

Should display only items from the two tables if their `ruleID`'s match and the `accountID` in the Rule table is `geoskygps@gmail.com`, but what happens for me is I get results from all `accountID` not just `geoskygps@gmail.com`.

I also tried using the `AND` clause instead of `WHERE` but I get the same exact results.

```
SELECT *
FROM Rule
INNER JOIN RuleList
WHERE Rule.ruleID = RuleList.ruleID
AND Rule.accountID = 'geoskygps@gmail.com'
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciated it.

Thanks,
Mike
this is for: show create Table Rule;

```
  Rule  | CREATE TABLE `Rule` (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `ruleID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `isCronRule` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ruleTag` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `selector` text,
  `actionMask` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cannedActions` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `minNotifyAge` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `triggerReset` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `notifyEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailSubject` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `emailText` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `smsText` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `useEmailWrapper` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ruleDisable` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ruleEnable` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sendCommand` text,
  `isActive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdateTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`,`ruleID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

This is for RuleList

```
| RuleList | CREATE TABLE `RuleList` (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `groupID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `statusCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ruleID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdateTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`,`deviceID`,`groupID`,`statusCode`,`ruleID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Are you certain that `Rule.accountID` contains email addresses? Are you sure it doesn't contain a number? Perhaps you should replace `accountId` with another column that contains an email address.

Comment: in inner join where you have relation?

Comment: Yes I am 100% certain that account ID is an email address. :)

Comment: Can you post some of the data in your `Rule` and `RuleList` tables? Otherwise, there isn't enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: Can you post an example of those tables or a schema of both tables ?

Comment: Also, please post the results of the following 2 queries: `show create table Rule; show create table RuleList;`

Comment: Will do, but just an FYI the query runs, except it completely ignores the WHERE clause.

Comment: I added the show create table Rule/RuleList; in the original question for you.

Comment: What happens for me in in mySQL id displays all results in the Table ignoring the WHERE caluse, but under accountID id changes everything to geoskygps@gmail.com but when I display it on a website with php the accountID stays the same for its respective account

Even when I use a simple query as this.


`select * from Rule, RuleList WHERE Rule.ruleID = RuleList.ruleID AND Rule.accountID='geoskygps@gmail.com'`

Comment: So I copied the two tables in a new DB and I keep getting the same weird results, Where should I look in mable table schema that might cause my weird issues with a JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I just tried the below. Your Code appeared to function as expected for the rough tables I created. Potentially the issue is in the data which you are using?

```
create table Rule(ruleID INTEGER,accountID text,data text);
insert into Rule values(1, 'geoskygps@gmail.com' , 'data');
insert into Rule values(2, 'nothing@gmail.com' , 'data');
insert into Rule values(3, 'geoskygps@gmail.com' , 'data');

create table Rulelist(ruleID INTEGER,accountID text,data text);
insert into Rulelist values(1, 'geoskygps@gmail.com' , 'data1');
insert into Rulelist values(2, 'geoskygps@gmail.com' , 'data1');
insert into Rulelist values(3, 'geoskygps@gmail.com' , 'data1');

select * FROM Rule
JOIN RUlelist
ON rule.ruleID = RuleList.ruleID
WHERE Rule.accountID = 'geoskygps@gmail.com'
```

returns the following:

```
ruleID | accountID           |  data |  ruleID |    accountID | data

1      | geoskygps@gmail.com |  data |  1      |    data      | data1

3      | geoskygps@gmail.com |  data |  3      |    data      | data1
```

Comment: ok my ruleID is a Varchar32 and its a column after accountID, not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: What happens for me in in mySQL id displays all results in the Table ignoring the WHERE caluse, but under accountID id changes everything to geoskygps@gmail.com but when I display it on a website with php the accountID stays the same for its respective account.

Comment: OK so this is weird, I created a differ DB on the same mySQL server and it works just find, what would make one DB react differently then the other one on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Here is the proper query.

I had to add a second parameter to my WHERE clause since both the databases hold multiples of the same record.

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM Rule 
 JOIN RuleList 
 ON Rule.ruleID = RuleList.ruleID 
 WHERE Rule.accountID = '$login_user' and RuleList.accountID ='$login_user';
```

Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score -1):

Rule is a reserved keyword in SQL. Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You could work around setting Rule in single quotes => `'Rule'.ruleID` and so on but i strongly recommend to rename it.

Comment: OP is using MySQL, not MS SQL Server. `Rule` is *not* a reserved word in MySQL. -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: it seem it reserved in T-SQL but question is for MySQL and I don't see rule in reserverd keywords https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: In any case, even if it were a reserved word, using a reserved word in this context would lead to a syntax error, not unexpected query results.